# writing content of act_evt_log table to a log file on server (periodically)

Tags: postgresql, activiti

The huge content of the `act_evt_log` table makes `activiti` processing slower.

I know the following solution:

- Disable the activitiEventLogging using the following code:

  ```
  <property name="enableDatabaseEventLogging" value="false" />
  ```

But I don't want this solution.

I want to take backup of that table in a file (any file) and then remove the content of it (or write to a file directly instead of using that table if possible).

Is there a way to get this done? If yes then how?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there are no foreign key constraints involved, you could

```
BEGIN;
ALTER TABLE act_evt_log RENAME TO act_evt_log_old;
CREATE TABLE act_evt_log (LIKE act_evt_log_old INCLUDING ALL);
COMMIT;
```

Then you could use `COPY` to write it to a server file:

```
COPY act_evt_log_old TO '/some/server/file' (FORMAT 'csv');
```

After that, you can drop the old table.